# CC65: Four lines bad, two lines good?

Tags: c, stdio, c64, ca65

I'm trying to do IO using `stdio.h` on a Commodore 64, but I'm having with even the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("Foo\n");
    printf("Bar\n");
    /* printf("Foo\n"); */
    /* printf("Bar\n"); */
}
```

The problem is, if I leave 2 `printf`s uncommented, then it works as expected. If I uncomment all four, then it doesn't work at all: if I `RUN` it, I just see the lines flashing by before the screen resets to just showing `READY.` on an empty screen.

If I have three, then it doesn't work for the first time (flashes to empty `READY.` screen) but if I `RUN` it again, then it works...

I should add that I've only tested this on VICE, not a real C64.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "doesn't work at all"?

Comment: what happens if you change main() return type to int and return 0 at its end?

Comment: @Devolus: Like I wrote, `RUN`ning it results in the showed lines quickly getting replaced by an empty screen with just a single `READY.` in the top-left corner. It's like as if after priting the lines, it also quickly executed a clearscreen instruction.

Comment: @Lazarus: it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Can you put a `sleep` or a `getch` at the end to see if this is after main.

Comment: @Devolus: OK I'm starting to think my CC65 installation is FUBAR... if I replace `main` with `{ sleep(2); printf("Foo\n");}` then first it immediately (no 2 second wait) goes to the empty `READY.` screen, and if I try to run it again, VICE tells me it caused the CPU to jam..

Comment: User says works as expected now that expectations were clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After following @Devolus's suggestion to do sanity checking with `sleep`, it turned out nothing, in general, was working properly. I've downgraded my CC65 installation from 2.13.9-svn5804 to 2.13.3, and that seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Thanks for sharing your solution!